# Groovy: redirect stdout to a file does not work

Tags: java, redirect, groovy, stdout

I'm just learning groovy. I have a very simple script that output some text to STDERR and STDOUT with `println`:

```
err = System.err    
resultStr = "test to print"
err.println resultStr
println resultStr
```

If I then run the script without redirection I get the `resultStr` string in the output two times.

If I redirect the output to a file with `test > test.txt`, the result string appears one time in the output (OK), test.txt is created (OK), but it's **empty**. I've tried to do `System.out.println` instead of `println` with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

If it's important, I'm on Windows 7. Just in case I've tried to redirect output of standard windows programs, like dir, and it works.

Groovy Version: 1.8.4 JVM: 1.7.0_02

**UPDATE**: i have also tried to create a simple ["Hello World"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) class in java (the same JVM). Redirection does work. So it should be something in Groovy.

**UPDATE 2**: After the comment from @socha23 that he can redirect successfully from the same script under Windows 7, I thought that the problem is not in the script but in Groovy installation, version conflicts or OS. So I've asked [similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/370782/stdout-redirection-to-a-file-does-not-work-if-groovy-script-run-directly-from-co) (sorry for cross-posting, but I really thought it's a borderline question).

Then I found out that redirection does not work properly if I run the script directly as `test.groovy > test.txt`. But if I run `groovy test.groovy > test.txt` it works. I'd still like to understand this behavior and correct if possible. Please visit the SU question. As for today 12/24, it's still unanswered.

I think it's clear now that it's not a programming question. Please recommend if I should delete it from here. Both questions are referring each other.

Comment: Is the file empty if you flush the stream before exiting?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö: I put `System.out.flush()` at the end of the script, but the file is still empty.

Comment: It works fine for me on Mac OS X with Groovy 1.8.3. I suspect it is something with Windows 7 (though even that is surprising).

Comment: Well, I'll try to reboot tomorrow and will see what happens. Can someone try this code on Windows machine? I'm using the latest Groovy version.

Comment: I just tried it on my Windows7 machine and it works fine.

Comment: @socha23: Please see the update 2. How exactly did you run the script under Windows?

Comment: I ran it as `groovy test.groovy > test.txt`.

Comment: @socha23: Have you tried the other way? If it won't work at all, you need to add `.groovy` to PATHEXT environment variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Windows 7 64-bit? Try if this hotfix from MS solves your problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971163/en-us
This may apply if output redirection does not work with a certain program, but output on console does. (For some reason, the hotfix does not install on my machine.)

As far as I understand the issue, if you call groovy directly there is no API call to CreateProcessWithTokenW  involved, whereas if you use the shell, that is "test.groovy > file.txt", it calls this API function, leading to the bug.

**UPDATE:**

I found out in the meantime that this Hotfix is included in Windows 7 SP1, this is why it will not install on your and on my machine. The only other related bug I found is this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321788, but it was supposedly fixed during Windows XP times.

I strongly suspect the output redirection code in Windows is still containing bugs, since I had the same problem as you with a different program and could fix it by changing the source code, but in a way that does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded the fix, but it said my OS is not supported. It's Windows 7 Pro 64-bit + SP1. :( Will check later.

Answer (score 0):

Your results make sense to me, the standard ">" redirect only works on standard out.  In both bash and, I'm pretty sure, DOS, you need to do "2>" to get the standard error output redirected to a file.  The following script proves this out, on bash at least.  The DOS command line worked pretty much the same for me.

```
System.out.println "Hello Standard Out"
System.err.println "Hello Standard Err"

println "Hello plain-jane println"
```

Simple redirect test has stdout.txt showing "Hello Standard Out" and "Hello plain-jane println" but NOT "Hello Standard Err", it comes out on the console.

```
bobk-mbp:hello bobk$ groovy StderrAndOut.groovy > stdout.txt
Hello Standard Err
bobk-mbp:hello bobk$
```

My next test explicitly redirects standard out and standard error resulting in stdout2.txt showing "Hello Standard Out" and "Hello plain-jane println" and stderr2.txt showing "Hello Standard Err".

```
bobk-mbp:hello bobk$ groovy StderrAndOut.groovy > stdout2.txt 2>stderr2.txt
bobk-mbp:hello bobk$
```

I am surprised that your results are any different in standard java as what you are trying to do has little to do with the VM and a lot to do with the shell.

Comment: These links are useful:  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

Comment: Please read the question again. I have no problems with STDERR and I don't want to redirect it. The problem is when I redirect STDOUT the file is created but it's empty, and the string (printed to stdout) does not appear in the console. The string to stderr does appear as expected.

Comment: Actually I have to update the question with some new information. It appears that the problem is really not with the script, but with the operation system. Please check it a little later.